# select list sending old value in ajax request

Tags: 7, ajax

I have a select list on custom module form, on it's select giving ajax call and populating the second select list. But when I select the value from the first list, it is passing old value (previously selected) to the callback function (It should send currently select value).
Following is my code.

```
  function get_subject($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['students'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => $student_array,
      '#title' => t('Students'),
      '#id' => 'students',
      '#value' => ($students != '') ? $students : '',
      '#required' => TRUE, 
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => '_subject_loader',
        'wrapper' => 'subject_div',
      ),
    );
    $form['subject'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => $subject_list,
      '#title' => t('subject'),
      '#id' => 'subject',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="subject_div">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#value' => ($subject != '') ? $subject: '',
      '#required' => TRUE 
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type'=>'submit',
      '#value'=>'Submit',
    );
    return $form;
  }

  function _subject_loader($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['subject'];
  }
```

Comment: The '#value' key provides a fixed value for an element. You should use '#default_value' for input fields. So that may be your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Form state input rather than using values in ajax call back like below:

```
if (isset($form_state['input']['students'])) {
    $student = $form_state['input']['students'];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return the `$form['subject']` you will be returning an array most likely, as the `$form` is a render array. You need to access the lists inside $form_state which hold the values of the submited form.

```
function _subject_loader($form, $form_state) {
  $user_input_values = $form_state->getUserInput();
  return $user_input_values['student'];
}
```